# How to get last inserted record Id in Gupta SQL Base

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase

I am new to Gupta Sql Base. I would like to know how to get the last inserted record in Gupta SQL

Comment: I know this has already been answered , but if you need to know more about SQLBase, here is a link to some manuals for every version from v8 thru v12.1  :  http://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SYSDBSequence.NextVal to generate your Primary Key, either within the Insert stmt, or prior to the Insert , then you can retrieve  it back immediately after the Insert by Selecting Where [Primary Key] = SYSDBSequence.Currval e.g.
`Select Name from Patient Where Patient_Id = SYSDBSequence.Currval`

Alternatively, If your Primary Key column has been defined as  AUTO_INCREMENT , you can select it back after the Insert using MAX( [Primary Key ] ) e.g.
`Select Name from Patient Where Patient_Id = (Select MAX( Patient_Id) from Patient )`

Alternatively, if none of the above, then write an Insert Trigger to either return it , or to store the PK in a table so you will always have the latest PK recorded for you.

You may like to join the Gupta users forum at [enter link description here](http://tdforum.daverabelink.net/index.php) or there is much archived information at [enter link description here](http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportforum/)

Comment: Is there any equivalent for MS SQL @@identity in Sql base? I am looking for a generic way. The MAX value will not be correct if we do multiple inserts at the same time right?

Comment: Then use SYSDBSequence.NextVal  to do the insert - and then SYSDBSequence.Currval will contain the value just inserted - exactly like @@Identity. Better still - you didn't need to define the column as an Identity column in the first place.